# How to take a uploaded file in django and pass to a function

Tags: python, django, csv

Hi upload csv files in the media folder and now i want to take this files to pass a list in python to make a pdf. How can i call this files in a fucntion in django or there is a better way to do it??

**This is how i upload the files:**

```
def subir_archivos(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['myfile']:
            myfile = request.FILES['myfile']
            fs = FileSystemStorage()
            filename = fs.save(myfile.name, myfile)
            uploaded_file_url = fs.url(filename)
            return render(request, 'subir_csv.html', {
                'uploaded_file_url': uploaded_file_url
            })
    return render(request, 'subir_csv.html')
```

**And the method to pass a csv to a python list:**

```
def csv_empresas(request):
    lista = []

    with open('media/empresas.csv') as csvfile:
        lector = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',',quotechar='|')
        for row in lector:
            lista.append(row)


    return render(request,'preparar_pdf.html',{"lista": lista})
```

Comment: so what problem are you facing

Comment: The problem is:  i need to make a pdf from 5 csv files (passing 5 list in the django function view)  and the names of the csv can be different so i dont know how to pass this 5 list to a function.

Comment: Its a bit difficult to explain sorry for my english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While uploading files, you can save all uploaded files in one folder inside media folder

Code to save uploaded files in folder called `upload_files`

```
def subir_archivos(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['myfile']:
        myfile = request.FILES['myfile']
        file_obj = myfile.read()
        media_path = settings.MEDIA_ROOT 
        file_path=  os.path.join(media_path, "upload_files")
        if not os.path.isdir(file_path):
            try:
                os.makedir(file_path)
            except OSError as e:
                pass
        file = os.path.join(file_path, myfile.name)
        with open(file, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(file_obj)
        uploaded_file_url = os.path.join("/media", "upload_files", myfile.name)
        return render(request, 'subir_csv.html', {
                'uploaded_file_url': uploaded_file_url
            })
    return render(request, 'subir_csv.html')
```

and code for getting all uploaded files

```
import os 
def csv_empresas(request):
    lista = []
    media_path = settings.MEDIA_ROOT
    file_path=  os.path.join(media_path, "upload_files") 
    files = os.listdir(file_path)
    for file in files:
        with open(file, 'rb') as csvfile:
            lector = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',',quotechar='|')
            for row in lector:
                lista.append(row) 
   return render(request,'preparar_pdf.html',{"lista": lista})
```